# catchTheEggs challenge from CodeFights: Can you help me find my mistake?

Tags: python, loops

This is a question from [CodeFights](https://codefights.com/challenge/7scRyRXmG5R8PigCY) but the general premise is this: You just got a job as the egg-catcher in a poorly-designed egg factory.
The chickens are all lined up in a row on one side of the factory.
Each chicken has a conveyor belt under it that is delivering dropped eggs to you.If you are at the end of a conveyor belt when the egg arrives, you catch it.If not, the egg falls onto the floor and you do not catch it.

During a "turn" eggs travel down the conveyor belts 1 positional unit.
You can move 1 position to the left, 1 position to the right, or stay where you are. Given the input. Return the maximum number of eggs that you could possibly catch during your shift.

---

Just to clear things up, conveyorLength just means your starting position. So if there are 5 chickens and cL = 3, then you can only catch eggs from conveyor 2,3,4 in the first round since you can stay put or move either direction in one increment. This question is kind of tricky because you have to find the BEST outcome, and there can be multiple paths the worker can take to catch all the eggs.

-An example: catchTheEggs(3, 1, [[1,3],[2],[3]]) = 3

-**ROUND 1:** Here n=3, cL=1 so in the first round, eggs from conveyor 1 and 3 drop [1,3], you are standing at cL=1 right now so you catch egg 1 and egg 3 falls.

-**ROUND 2:** cL=1 because you decided not to move in the last round. This time only egg 2 drops, so you move to cL=2 to catch it.

-**ROUND 3:** cL=2 because you moved to catch the egg from the second round. This time egg from conveyor 3 drops so you move to catch it.

-In total you caught 3 eggs.

```
def catchTheEggs(numberOfChickens, conveyorLength, eggs):
# i changed the name of the variables for convenience sake
n = numberOfChickens
cL = conveyorLength
catch = 0

for i in range(0, len(eggs)):

    for j in range(0, len(eggs[i])):
        # is it possible to catch the egg
        if ((eggs[i][j] + 1) == cL) or ((eggs[i][j] - 1) == cL) or (eggs[i][j] == cL):
            cL = eggs[i][j]
            catch += 1
        # say you are at cL=1, and eggs from conveyor 4 drop 4 times: 
        # [[4],[4],[4],[4]] then you should move to conveyor 2, then 3
        # and for the last 2 rounds you can catch them. 
        # so I'm accounting for a scenario like that.   
        elif (abs(len(eggs)) >= n):
            cL += 1

return catch
```

I'm having trouble fulfilling this test case:

```
catchTheEggs(4,2,[[1,4],[1,2,4],[1,3],[2],[1,2,4],[2,3],[3],[2],[1,3,4],[3,4],[1]])
```

It should give 10, but my code gives me 14.

Comment: The way SO usually works is *you* find where the mistake is and we advise why it happened, how to fix it, and how to avoid it in future. Break down your code, `print` bits you are unsure about, follow @Georgy's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that multiple eggs can be caught in a single round.

Your first "if" statement would allow the egg-catcher to catch a single egg if they are one square away from it. However, there is no condition to prevent the egg-catcher from catching another egg once they have caught the first one.

---

Example:

If *eggs*[i] = [2,3] and *cL* = 2, the "j" for loop would iterate twice (as len(*eggs*[i]) = 2).

On the second iteration, *eggs*[i][0] = 2 would be considered, and as *cL* = 2, the egg would be caught. *catch* would also be incremented here, and *cL* would remain 2.

On the second iteration, *eggs*[i][1] would equal 3, and as *cL* = 2, the egg would also be caught.

---

Because of this, some *eggs* values will cause *cL* to be incremented twice, such as [1,2,4] (where eggs in position 1 and 2 are both caught). This is the cause of the output 14 instead of 10.

To rectify this, you need to insert either a *break* statement, or another Boolean variable that prevents more than one move per round into the "j" for loop.